# Sprite PNG is appearing distorted

Tags: image, google-chrome, png, sprite, internet-explorer-11

We are using a png/8 sprite on a client's website. He is reporting the image is appearing distorted for him and on other computers on the company.

Here's how it should look:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENsVB.jpg

And here is the print screen the client sent us:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu68m.jpg

I have tried donloading and exporting it again, uploading again. The problem is: On our computers it looks fine, so it's hard to test it. Our client is viewing it in IE: 11 and Google chrome: 41.0.272.118.

Has anyone seen this type of error before?

Answer (score 0):

It may be the device-pixel-ratio is better than 160dpi; that'd throw off some CSS used for spriting.

If this shows "1" for you and a different value for them, I'd dig farther on that one.  You could probably test this by hitting the site with an iPhone or newer Android device; they have >1.0 pixel ratios.

http://www.devicepixelratio.com/

Edit: this would also show up across-browsers on their end, as it's tied to the hardware, and not IE11.

Comment: Client sent me a print of the result, his computer shows 1. It's a desktop computer.

Comment: (Will try a separate answer to split these up.)

Answer (score 0):

My bet in that case is the PNG is somehow broken.

graphicdesign.stackexchange.com might be more useful; I don't know if this is fixable in CSS.  (Might be; look for hacks around image backgrounds as well.)

Looking around, if you have Photoshop, you might try saving the original image, then creating a copy and changing this setting:

```
Image -> Mode -> Check "RGB Color"
```

Alternatively, try opening the image in pixlr.com, change anything however slightly, then save and use that one.

My strong suspicion is something in the way the PNG/8 is saved (maybe the alpha channel) is the issue, not any CSS you've written.  Good luck!